# Customize icon tabs Ionic 3

Tags: css, angular, sass, ionic2

I am trying to apply customize icons for ionic tabs but it's showing only inactive tab icon, on clicking another tab it's not showing anything

tabs.scss file

```
.tabs{
  a[aria-selected=false]{
    .ion-md-tab1 {
      max-width: 26px !important;
      content: url("../assets/imgs/inactive-tab1.png") !important; }
    }
.ion-md-tab2 {
          max-width: 26px !important;
          content: url("../assets/imgs/inactive-tab2.png") !important; 
     }
        }
  a[aria-selected=true]{
    .tabs-md-tab1 {
      max-width: 26px !important;
      content: url("../assets/imgs/active-tab1.png") !important;
    }
     .ion-md-tab2 {
      max-width: 26px !important;
      content: url("../assets/imgs/inactive-tab2.png") !important; 
     }
  }
}
```

tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabIcon="tab1"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabIcon="tab2"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.tabs{
    .ion-md-tab1[ng-reflect-is-active="true"] {
      max-width: 26px !important;
      content: url("../assets/imgs/inactive-tab1.png") !important; }
    .ion-md-tab2[ng-reflect-is-active="true"] {
          max-width: 26px !important;
          content: url("../assets/imgs/inactive-tab2.png") !important;}
    .tabs-md-tab1[ng-reflect-is-active="false"] {
      max-width: 26px !important;
      content: url("../assets/imgs/active-tab1.png") !important;
    }
     .ion-md-tab2[ng-reflect-is-active="false"] {
      max-width: 26px !important;
      content: url("../assets/imgs/inactive-tab2.png") !important; 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use custom icon in your app, here is a solution that worked great for me.

1. Put your .svg icon file(s) in:

   /src/assets/icons/...
2. In your app.scss file, add this scss code:

   ```
   ion-icon {
       &[class*="prefix-"] {
           mask-size: contain;
           mask-position: 50% 50%;
           mask-repeat: no-repeat;
           background: currentColor;
           width: 1em;
           height: 1em;
       }
   // custom icons
       &[class*="prefix-categories"] {
           mask-image: url(../assets/icon/ic_categories.svg);
       }
       &[class*="prefix-menu"] {
           mask-image: url(../assets/icon/ic_menu.svg);
       }
   }
   ```
3. and on your html tabs code here

   ```
   <ion-tabs>
       <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Title" tabIcon="prefix-name"></ion-tab>
   </ion-tabs>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-reflect-is-active="true"` is not working in the production build use this; it works fine for me:

```
.tabs {
    a[aria-selected=true] {
      .ion-md-tab1 {
        max-width: 26px !important;
        background: url("../assets/imgs/svg/ic_home_active.svg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
      }
    }
  }
```